# Delete a line in multiple text files with the same line beginning but varying line ending using Python v3.5

Tags: python, file, text, editing

I have a folder full of .GPS files, e.g. 1.GPS, 2.GPS, etc...
Within each file is the following five lines:

```
Trace #1 at position 0.004610
$GNGSA,A,3,02,06,12,19,24,25,,,,,,,2.2,1.0,2.0*21
$GNGSA,A,3,75,86,87,,,,,,,,,,2.2,1.0,2.0*2C
$GNVTG,39.0304,T,39.0304,M,0.029,N,0.054,K,D*32
$GNGGA,233701.00,3731.1972590,S,14544.3073733,E,4,09,1.0,514.675,M,,,0.49,3023*27
```

...followed by the same data structure, with different values, over the next five lines:

```
Trace #6 at position 0.249839
$GNGSA,A,3,02,06,12,19,24,25,,,,,,,2.2,1.0,2.0*21
$GNGSA,A,3,75,86,87,,,,,,,,,,2.2,1.0,2.0*2C
$GNVTG,247.2375,T,247.2375,M,0.081,N,0.149,K,D*3D
$GNGGA,233706.00,3731.1971997,S,14544.3075178,E,4,09,1.0,514.689,M,,,0.71,3023*2F
```

(I realise the values after the $GNGSA lines don't vary in the above example. This is just a bad example... in the real dataset they do vary!)

I need to remove the lines that begin with "$GNGSA" and "$GNVTG" (i.e. I need to delete lines 2, 3, and 4 from each group of five lines within each .GPS file).

This five-line pattern continues for a varying number of times throughout each file (for some files, there might only be two five-line groups, while other files might have hundreds of the five-line groups). Hence, deleting these lines based on the line number will not work (because the line number would be variable).

The problem I am having (as seen in the above examples) is that the text that follows the "$GNGSA" or "$GNVTG" varies.

I'm currently learning Python (I'm using v3.5), so figured this would make for a good project for me to learn a few new tricks...

**What I've tried already:**

So far, I've managed to create the code to loop through the entire folder:

```
import os

indir = '/Users/dhunter/GRID01/'  # input directory
for i in os.listdir(indir):  # for each "i" (iteration) within the indir variable directory...
    if i.endswith('.GPS'):  # if the filename of an iteration ends with .GPS, then...
        print(i + ' loaded')  # print the filename to CLI, simply for debugging purposes.
        with open(indir + i, 'r') as my_file:  # open the iteration file
            file_lines = my_file.readlines()    # uses the readlines method to create a list of all lines in the file.
            print(file_lines)  # this prints the entire contents of each file to CLI for debugging purposes.
```

Everything in the above works perfectly.

**What I need help with:**

1. How do I detect and delete the lines themselves, and then save the file (to the same location; there is no need to save to a different filename)?
2. The filenames - which usually end with ".GPS" - sometimes end with ".gps" instead (the only difference being the case). My above code will only work with the uppercase files. Besides completely duplicating the code and changing the endswith argument, how do I make it work with both cases?

In the end, my file needs to look something like this:

```
Trace #1 at position 0.004610
$GNGGA,233701.00,3731.1972590,S,14544.3073733,E,4,09,1.0,514.675,M,,,0.49,3023*27
Trace #6 at position 0.249839
$GNGGA,233706.00,3731.1971997,S,14544.3075178,E,4,09,1.0,514.689,M,,,0.71,3023*2F
```

Any suggestions, please? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on suggestions by Avinash Raj, tdelaney, and Sampson Oliver, here on Stack Overflow, and another friend who helped privately, here is the solution that is now working:

```
import os
indir = '/Users/dhunter/GRID01/'  # input directory
for i in os.listdir(indir):  # for each "i" (iteration) within the indir variable directory...
    if i.lower().endswith('.gps'):  # if the filename of an iteration ends with .GPS, then...
        if not i.lower().endswith('.gpsnew.gps'):  # if the filename does not end with .gpsnew.gps, then...
            print(i + ' loaded')  # print the filename to CLI.
            with open (indir + i, 'r') as my_file:
                for line in my_file:
                    if not line.startswith('$GNGSA'):
                        if not line.startswith('$GNVTG'):
                            with open(indir + i + 'new.gps', 'a') as outputfile:
                                outputfile.write(line)
                                outputfile.write('\r\n')
```

(You'll see I had to add in another layer of if statement to stop it from using the output files from previous uses of the script "if not i.lower().endswith('.gpsnew.gps'):", but this line can easily be deleted for anyone who uses these instructions in future)

We switched the open mode on the third-last line to "a" for append, so that it would save all the right lines to the file, rather than overwriting each time.

We also added in the final line to add a line break at the end of each line.

Thanks everyone for their help, explanations, and suggestions. Hopefully this solution will be useful to someone in future. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.

```
import os

indir = '/Users/dhunter/GRID01/'  # input directory
for i in os.listdir(indir):  # for each "i" (iteration) within the indir variable directory...
    if i.endswith('.GPS'):  # if the filename of an iteration ends with .GPS, then...
        print(i + ' loaded')  # print the filename to CLI, simply for debugging purposes.
        with open(indir + i, 'r') as my_file:  # open the iteration file
            for line in my_file:
                if not line.startswith('$GNGSA') and not line.startswith('$GNVTG'):

                    print(line)
```

Comment: Ah, of course. The old "not" idea. Silly me! Thanks, Avinash. That prints the correct lines to the terminal. However, when I then add to it: with open(indir + i + 'new.gps', 'w') as my_file2:   (new line in code) my_file2.writelines(line)`, it just deletes everything in the new file, except for the very first line in the file.

Comment: don't use writelines, just use `output_fileobj.write(line)`

Comment: Use `with open(indir + i) as my_file, open(indir + i + 'new.gps') out_file:` then `out_file.write(line)` as they are discovered. Also, `if i.lower().endswith('.gps')` would get rid of your case issue.

Comment: Sorry, Avinash - I did some extensive Googling but don't understand what you mean by using output_fileobj.write(line). I also don't understand your solution, @tdelaney... could you please post it as a new possible answer so that I can see line breaks and ask specific questions about it? Thanks. :)

Comment: @tdelaney - thanks - your solution "if i.lower().endswith('.gps')" fixed my case problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

As per what the others have said, you're on the right track! Where you're going wrong is in the case-sensitive file extension check, and in reading in the entire file contents at once (this isn't per se wrong, but it's probably adding complexity we won't need).

I've commented your code, removing all the debug stuff for simplicity, to illustrate what I mean:

```
import os

indir = '/path/to/files'
for i in os.listdir(indir):
if i.endswith('.GPS'): #This CASE SENSITIVELY checks the file extension
    with open(indir + i, 'r') as my_file: # Opens the file
        file_lines = my_file.readlines() # This reads the ENTIRE file at once into an array of lines
```

So we need to fix the case sensitivity issue, and instead of reading in all the lines, we'll instead read the file line-by-line, check each line to see if we want to discard it or not, and write the lines we're interested in into an output file.

So, incorporating @tdelaney's case-insensitive fix for file name, we replace line #5 with

```
if i.lower().endswith('.gps'): # Case-insensitively check the file name
```

and instead of reading in the entire file at once, we'll instead iterate over the file stream and print each desired line out

```
with open(indir + i) as in_file, open(indir + i + 'new.gps') as out_file: # Open the input file for reading and creates + opens a new output file for writing - thanks @tdelaney once again!
    for line in in_file # This reads each line one-by-one from the in file
        if not line.startswith('$GNGSA') and not line.startswith('$GNVTG'): # Check the line has what we want (thanks Avinash)
            out_file.write(line + "\n") # Write the line to the new output file
```

Note that you should make certain that you open the output file OUTSIDE of the 'for line in in_file' loop, or else the file will be overwritten on every iteration which will erase what you've already written to it so far (I suspect this is the issue you've had with the previous answers). Open both files at the same time and you can't go wrong.

Alternatively, you can specify the file access mode when you open the file, as per

```
with open(indir + i + 'new.gps', 'a'):
```

which will open the file in append-mode, which is a specialised from of write-mode that preserves the original contents of the file, and appends new data to it instead of overwriting existing data.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, @Sampson. That makes a lot more sense now. :) However, I get a syntax error for the line "with open(indir + i) as in_file, open(indir + i + 'new.gps') out_file:"  - the arrow in the error points to the last e in 'out_file:' at the end of that line...

Comment: Sorry, that line is missing a second 'as', as in `with open(indir + i) as in_file, open(indir + i + 'new.gps') as out_file:` Will update my answer.

Comment: Ah yep, I tried that too at the time I posted my first comment, but got a different error when trying it, on the final line:    out_file.write(line)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable - presumably a permissions error but I don't know how to fix it. Thanks again for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

**2. The filenames:**

The `if` accepts any expression returning a truth value, and you can combine expressions with the standart boolean operators: `if i.endswith('.GPS') or i.endswith('.gps')`. 
You can also put the `... and ...` expression after the `if` in brackets, to feel more sure, but it's not neccessary.

Alternatively, as a less universal solution, (but since you wanted to learn a few tricks :)) you can use string manipulation in this case: an object of type `string` has a lot of methods. `'.gps'.upper()` gives `'.GPS'` -- try, if you can make use of this! (even a printed string is a string object, but your variables behave the same).

**1. Finding the Lines:**

As you can see in the other solution, you need not read out all of your lines, you can check if want to have them 'on the fly'. But I will stick to your approach with `readlines`. It gives you a list, and lists support indexing and slicing. Try:

`anylist[stratindex, endindex, stride]`, for any values, so for example try: `newlist = range(100)[1::5]`.

It's always helpfull to try out the easy basic operations in interactive mode, or at the beginning of your script. Here `range(100)` is just some sample list. Here you see, how the python `for`-syntax works, differently than in other languages: you can iterate over any list, and if you just need integers, you create a list with integers with `range()`.

So this will work the same with any other list -- e.g. the one you get from `readlines()`

This selects a slice from the list, beginnig with the second element, ending at the end (since the end index is omitted), and taking every 5th element. Now you have this sub-list, you can just revome it from the original. So for the example with the range:

```
a = range(100)
del(a[1::5])
print a
```

So you see, that the appropriate items have been removed. Now do the same with your `file_lines`, and then proceed to remove the other lines you want to remove.

Then, in a new `with` block, open the file for writing and do `writelines(file_lines)`, so the remainig lines are written back to the file.

Of course you can also take the approach to look for the content of each line with a `for` loop over your list and `startswith()`. Or you can combine the approaches, and check, if deleting lines by number leaves the right starts, so you can print an error if something is unexpected...

**3. Saving the file**

You can close your file after you have the lines saved in the `readlines()`. In fact this is done automatically at the end of the `with`-block. Then just open it in `'w'` mode instead of `'r'` and do `yourfilename.writelines(yourlist)`. You don't need to save, it's saven on closing.

Comment: Thanks, Ilja, for your explanation. I understood your filename solution - that works perfectly, thank you. However, I did not understand your other solutions at all. From what I can gather, your "mylist[stratindex..." solution requires me to define a range for the search (i.e. if range(100), it will search only the first 100 lines of each file... is that correct? If so, should I just set that range to e.g. 100000 so that it doesn't really matter how long the file is? I also didn't understand your paragraph "This.... ...shorter list." Can you please clarify? Thanks again. :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, my example did not work ... I didn't notice, thank you for your comment.
Now I have some correct code, and hopefully also a better explanation. The main thing you learn from this is slicing lists.